# Call a Hash value with a variable - Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, variables, hash

How can I call a hash value with a variable?

I have a hash like this:`data = {"5/3/2013 13:31:13"=>{:open=>65, :closed=>835}}`

```
datasequences.each do |seq_title|
 sequence = Hash.new(0)
 sequence[:title] = seq_title
 sequence_data = Array.new(0)
 data.each do |key, value|
  puts value[#{seq_title.to_sym}]
  # More code...
 end
end
```

The per the Hash (`data`), the value of `seq_title` will be `open` and then `closed`.

For example if I change the code to read

```
datasequences.each do |seq_title|
 sequence = Hash.new(0)
 sequence[:title] = seq_title
 sequence_data = Array.new(0)
 data.each do |key, value|
  puts value[:open]
  # More code...
 end
end
```

In the above code Ruby outputs 65, but I want value[var] (not hardcoded) so it can output 65 and through the next iteration 835.

Comment: what does `[VARIABLE] (:open, then :closed)` mean it?

Comment: I want to call the value of the hash like this value[#{seq_title.to_sym}] so value[var] not hardcoded. In the example it could be value[:open] or value[:closed].

Comment: in this case `{"5/1/2013 10:42:40":{"open":10,"closed":345},{"5/2/2013 10:42:40":{"open":-1,"closed":700},{"5/3/2013 10:42:40":{"open":-29,"closed":604}}` what value you would expect? why you don't think `values_at` will not work?

Comment: your internal hash only has two values for `:open` and `:close` as you mentioned. Why then I will assume that there can be other keys also?

Comment: That's why I'm using a variable -- because the data will vary.

Comment: what is `datasequences`? is it Hash or Array? Who will gonna to assume it? whose responsibility is it to mention? accepted answer assume `datasequences = [ :open, :closed ]`. Did you mention that?

Comment: @Priti, it's an `Array`, but that is irrelevant. I explained what values it holds `:open` and `:closed` -- from the data hash in my question. From that information you could use reasoning to understand that if there were more value keys they would be there as well. I'm not sure why it matters either way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the key with a variable:

```
% irb
irb> data = {  "5/3/2013 13:31:13"=>{:open=>65, :closed=>835}, "5/4/2013 14:41:14"=>{:open=>56, :closed=>538} }
# => {"5/3/2013 13:31:13"=>{:open=>65, :closed=>835}, "5/4/2013 14:41:14"=>{:open=>56, :closed=>538}} 
irb> datasequences = [ :open, :closed ]
# => [:open, :closed] 
irb> datasequences.each do |seq_title|
irb|   puts "seq_title is #{seq_title.inspect}"
irb|   data.each do |key, value|
irb|     puts "\t#{value[seq_title]} at #{key}"
irb|   end
irb| end
seq_title is :open
  65 at 5/3/2013 13:31:13
  56 at 5/4/2013 14:41:14
seq_title is :closed
  835 at 5/3/2013 13:31:13
  538 at 5/4/2013 14:41:14
# => [:open, :closed]
```

Comment: @에이바 you have given less data and expecting others to guess and answer,when they answered you are keep adding all your requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means @Priti.

Comment: Please remove the irb noise.

Comment: @에이바 you don't because you deleted your comment. every time you were adding incrementally requirement. Why you didn't put them when you posted it first. the answer  you have accepted no way connected to the post in your original.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question @Priti.

Answer (score 1):

Since the value is itself a hash, you print the keys and values like this:

```
data.each do |key, value|
  value.each do |k,v|
    puts "#{k}: #{v}"
  end
  # More code...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Hash#values_at`, like below:

```
data = {"5/1/2013 10:42:40" => {"open" => 10,"closed" => 345},"5/2/2013 10:42:40" => {"open" => -1,"closed" => 700}}
datasequences = [ :open, :closed ]

data.each do |k,v|
  p v.values_at(*datasequences.map(&:to_s))
end
```

***output:***

```
[10, 345]
[-1, 700]
```